# What are the units and format of data in the mission planner/pixhawk log file?

Tags: python

I am trying to interpret data from the pixhawk (PH) bin log file. I copied the bin log file from the PH flash drive to my hard drive and converted to a CSV text log file using mission planner. I opened the CSV file in excel and sorted based on the first column 'MAG'. Below is a screenshot of some of the magnetometer data:
[image]

But it is very unclear how to interpret this. Here are the two challenges I'm facing:
1) Time is a 9-digit number. Any idea what the units are (possibly ms) and how to convert this to actual time?
2) MagX, MagY, and MagZ are obviously the x, y, and z components of the magnetic field. But what are the units? And do I need to add the offsets OfsX, OfsY, and OfsZ to get the actual field or has that already been taken into account?

Once I understand these points, I will be using python to read and analyze the mag data, which should be very straightforward.

Comment: please remove that tag. If you can't find any valid tags that doesn't mean you can add some random tags

Comment: @Billa, I'm wondering if you are able to create a pixhawk tag that I could apply to the post. Maybe my question is actually super hard, but I doubt it. Just not attracting the right group of experts with such limited tags.

Comment: You attracted wrong group of experts with your random tags, i am one among them.

Comment: So @Billa, are you able to create a pixhawk tag and apply it?

Comment: It would be much appreciated!